# Today App Extension Playing for Video is working fine but when trying to play Audio is not working properly in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, today-extension

In my Today App Extension video is playing properly but when trying to play Audio from url is not working.

---

1. For Playing video from url Code is below working fine.

   ```
   func playVideo() {

       let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")
       let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
       let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
       playerViewController.player = player
       self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
           playerViewController.player!.play()
       }
   }
   ```
2. but for Playing Audio from url in not working

   ```
   func playAudio()

       var player:AVPlayer?
       var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
       let url = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3")
       let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
       player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

       let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
       playerLayer.frame=CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100, height:100)
       self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

       if player?.rate == 0 {
           player!.play()
       } else {
           player!.pause()
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I pasted your audio file URL into Chrome and Safari and got „Access Denied”. Have you checked that it is accessible on your end? Have you tried inspecting the `error` property of `playerItem`?

Comment: in browser Audio playing fine

Comment: And have you done any logging in in the browser before and may have a cookie set allowing you access to the file?

Comment: yes its allows me to play without any logging

Comment: no need for any access to play this, Directly past url in chrome & its play